# Docker RUN does NOT persist files

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a problem with Docker which does not persist commands launch via "RUN".

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM jenkins:latest

RUN echo "foo" > /var/jenkins_home/toto ; ls -alh  /var/jenkins_home
RUN ls -alh  /var/jenkins_home

RUN rm /var/jenkins_home/.bash_logout  ; ls -alh  /var/jenkins_home
RUN ls -alh  /var/jenkins_home

RUN echo "bar" >> /var/jenkins_home/.profile ; cat /var/jenkins_home/.profile
RUN  cat /var/jenkins_home/.profile
```

And here is the output :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 373.8 kB Step 1 : FROM jenkins:latest  ---> fc39417bd5fb Step 2 : RUN echo "foo" > /var/jenkins_home/toto ; ls -alh  /var/jenkins_home  ---> Using cache 
---> c614b13d9d83 Step 3 : RUN ls -alh  /var/jenkins_home  ---> Using cache  ---> 8a16a0c92f67 Step 4 : RUN rm /var/jenkins_home/.bash_logout  ; ls -alh  /var/jenkins_home  ---> Using cache  ---> f6ca5d5bdc64 Step 5 : RUN ls -alh  /var/jenkins_home
---> Using cache  ---> 3372c3275b1b Step 6 : RUN echo "bar" >> /var/jenkins_home/.profile ; cat /var/jenkins_home/.profile  ---> Running in 79842be2c6e3
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then     . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" fi bar  ---> 28559b8fe041 Removing intermediate container 79842be2c6e3 Step 7 : RUN cat /var/jenkins_home/.profile  ---> Running in c694e0cb5866
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then     . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" fi  ---> b7e47d65d65e Removing intermediate container c694e0cb5866 Successfully built b7e47d65d65e
```

Do you guys know why "foo" file is not persisted on step 3? Why ".bash_logout" file is recreated on step 5? Why "bar" is not in my ".profile" file anymore on step 7?

And of course, if I start a container based on this image, none of my modifications are persisted... so my Dockerfile is... useless. Any clue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason those changes are not persisted, is that they are inside a *volume* the Jenkins Dockerfile [marks `/var/jenkins_home/` as a `VOLUME`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/683b0d6ed17016ee3211f247304ef2f265102c2b/Dockerfile#L13-L15).

Information inside volumes is not persisted during `docker build`, or more precisely; each build-step creates a *new* volume based on the image's content, discarding the volume that was used in the previous build step.

#### How to resolve this?

I think the best way to resolve this, is to;

- Add the files you want to modify inside `jenkins_home` in a different location inside the image, e.g. `/var/jenkins_home_overrides/`
- Create a custom entrypoint based on, or "wrapping", [the default entrypoint script](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/683b0d6ed17016ee3211f247304ef2f265102c2b/Dockerfile#L13-L15) that copies the content of your `jenkins_home_overrides` to `jenkins_home` the first time the container is started.

**Actually...**

And just when I wrote that up; It looks like the official Jenkins image already support this out of the box;
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/683b0d6ed17016ee3211f247304ef2f265102c2b/jenkins.sh#L5-L23

[According to the documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/683b0d6ed17016ee3211f247304ef2f265102c2b/README.md#installing-more-tools), you need to add your files to the `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/` directory, and those will be copied to `/var/jenkins/home` upon start.

Also see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24986

Comment: Excellent. That was it. I used to write to another folder and didn't notice that changing my dest folder have such an impact. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks bro. This answer should be added to the official docker jenkins image.

Comment: If you have a line like `FROM jenkins:latest` how can you find the source of the corresponding Dockerfile?

Comment: There is no direct way to find back the Dockerfile for an image, but for official images on Docker hub, the Dockerfile corresponding with each tag is linked from the repository description on Docker Hub; in this case look under the "supported tags" section on https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins. Be aware though that the `jenkins` image on Docker Hub was deprecated in favor of https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins which doesn't appear to have a link to the Dockerfile. That said, without a Dockerfile, you can still `docker image inspect <image>` an image to find out if it uses volumes.