# Dockerfile unexpected behaviour between RUN commands

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a weird issue trying to execute several RUN commands sequentially.

The goal is to copy a folder. 
If I list the files in target folder:

- it works in the same RUN with && ls
- it does not work in another RUN

Here is the trace:

```
Step 6 : RUN cp -rf /app/httpd/htdocs/* /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/ && ls /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/
 ---> Running in 05842445d075
modules
tests
 ---> 05c51d512f60
Removing intermediate container 05842445d075
Step 7 : RUN ls /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/
 ---> Running in aa217a8edc37
 ---> 095c9f8ac8e7
```

Do you have any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: post the Dockerfile

Comment: at the end of the build, do you have your files?

Comment: Nothing interesting in my Dockerfile. 
I think the problem is probably in the parent Dockerfile 
FROM rhscl/httpd-24-rhel7:2.4-10

Comment: And no files at the end, which is the problem

Answer (score 1):

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34843099/6309), that could happen if the Dockerfile declared first a [`VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/volume).

Any file copied into a `VOLUME` would be discarded, as each build-step creates a new volume based on the image's content, discarding the volume that was used in the previous build step.